# WPF Using bindings to ViewModel in style used to change controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The objective is to swap the control at runtime based on a property in my ViewModel, and have the displayed control be have a binding that updates the properties in the ViewModel. I started by creating the following Style in the View.xaml:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="DisplayTextOrButton" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TextNotButton}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Content="{Binding SomeText}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TextNotButton}" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="{Binding ButtonText}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Note that the bindings `LabelText` and `ButtonText` are the bindings to the properties in the ViewModel.

Then further on in the View.xaml I have the following:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding TextNotButton}"
                Style="{StaticResource DisplayTextOrButton}">

</ContentControl>
```

Finally, the ViewModel.cs has the following properties:

```
private bool textNotButton;
public bool TextNotButton
{
  get => this.textNotButton;
  set
  {
    this.textNoButton = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged("TextNotButton");
  }
}

private string someText;
public string SomeText
{
  get => this.someText;
  set
  {
    this.someText = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged("SomeText");
  }
}

private string buttonText;
public string ButtonText
{
  get => this.buttonText;
  set
  {
    this.buttonText = value;
    this.OnPropertyChanged("ButtonText");
  }
}
```

The style works well for swapping between the label and the button, but changing the text in the TextBox does not update the property in the ViewModel, and the Button's text is empty (I imagine because the binding hasn't worked)

I believe this is because the style is a static resource so the bindings `SomeText` and `ButtonText` in the style aren't actually the bindings in the ViewModel, but I'm not sure how to pass the reference of the other properties into the style. Or even if that's a thing. I'm pretty new to XAML so not sure on how to handle this

Comment: You probably wanted to write `<ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource DisplayTextOrButton}"/>`. Otherwise the Bindings in the ContentControl Style would try to resolve their Paths relative to the bool TextNotButton value, not the view model instance.

Comment: @Clemens that did the trick, thank you